# Affect of angular momentum in gravitational force

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, spacetime

**As far as I know:**

The gravitational force occurs due to curve in spacetime. A curve in spacetime occurs due to energy. So my question is the increase in angular momentum is also increase in gravitational force? For example a spinning blackhole would apply more gravitational force compared to a non spinning one. Because if its *spinning* it has more energy.

Please correct me if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Indeed, the gravitational field of a spinning black hole (Kerr metric) is different from that of a non-rotating one (Swarzschild metric). It is possible to extract the rotational energy from the Kerr black hole through the Penrose process.

Answer (score 1):

> The gravitational force occurs due to curve in spacetime

Curvature of spacetime is related to tidal forces. Because gravitational fields are non uniform, tidal forces are always present => spacetime curvature.

.

> A curve in spacetime occurs due to energy

yes, but more energy doesn't mean more curvature. Our Moon has more spacetime curvature at its surface than the surface of the sun.

Increase in angular momentum can even decrease gravitational force. If the Earth was perfectly spherical, $g$ would be smaller at equator than at the poles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain how our moon has more spacetime curvature at its surface compared to sun's surface ?

Comment: Spacetime curvature is measured by the Riemann tensor. For a spherical symmetric body most of its non zero components are proportional to the density, not to its total mass. Gas giants as the Sun and Jupiter are less dense than Earth and the Moon.